# How to send a salt from one function to another in C programming

Tags: c, linux, cryptography, password-encryption

I'm working with a project where I want to send the salt for a hashed password from one function to another, and I keep getting a weird output, and was wondering if anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <sys/random.h>

char superSalt[];
void function1(){
char salt[13]="$1$abcdefgh$";
getrandom(salt+3,8,0);
    for(unsigned int i=3;i<11;i++){
        salt[i]=saltchars[salt[i] & 0x3f];
    }
    superSalt = salt;
}

void function2(){
    printf("salt: %s\n", superSalt);
}
```

when I print it out in function 1, I can read it, but I can't read it if I print it in function2, so it might just be me who doesn't understand how to utilize the variables, I guess?

Comment: You allocate `salt[13]` statically, it gets destroyed when `function1` exits so the pointer that `superSalt` points to just points to some random memory address that no longer contains your data.

Comment: you have a couple of errors. char `superSalt[]` is not allowed in C, there is no such assignment as `superSalt = salt`, you have to use memcopy or a loop

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

1. `superSalt[]` is not allowed in `C`. You have to give a size.
2. Secondly, you did not modify the `superSalt` in the `function1`
3. Using global variables are not advised, leaving to remove it to you.

header is not included.

```
char superSalt[13];

void function1(){
    char salt[13]="$1$abcdefgh$";
    getrandom(salt+3,8,0);
    for(unsigned int i=3;i<11;i++){
        superSalt[i]=salt[salt[i] & 0x3f];
    }
}

void function2(){
    printf("superSalt:");
    for(unsigned int i=3;i<11;i++){
        printf("%c",superSalt[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    function1();
    function2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the question you asked that you want to pass salt from one function to another function but in fact you are not passing anything, you are trying to use a global variable to store salt value and use it in a different function (which has it's own issues and has been rightly pointed out by @kelalaka) but if you want to stick to your original question in which you really want to pass the salt value to another function then you can rewrite your code something like this :

```
#include <sys/random.h>

//char superSalt[] --- Not required anymore;
void function1(){
char salt[13]="$1$abcdefgh$";
getrandom(salt+3,8,0);
for(unsigned int i=3;i<11;i++){
    salt[i]=saltchars[salt[i] & 0x3f];
}
function2(salt);
}

void function2(char * salt){
 printf("salt: %s\n", salt);
}
```